# Arming an AreoStar ESC with Raspberry Pi to manage brushless motors

Tags: gpio

I am trying to set up a brushless motor so I can control it via python.

I have a [AreoStar ESC](https://hobbyking.com/en_us/aerostar-rvs-40a-electronic-speed-controller-w-reverse-function-and-2a-bec-2-4s.html?gclid=Cj0KCQjwyYKUBhDJARIsAMj9lkGtJwkT5d3vKBGiDXJzRJzlR3Qbi-ljwLNo5AwRcBqTlMSJu-V0ro4aAva1EALw_wcB&gclid=Cj0KCQjwyYKUBhDJARIsAMj9lkGtJwkT5d3vKBGiDXJzRJzlR3Qbi-ljwLNo5AwRcBqTlMSJu-V0ro4aAva1EALw_wcB) and [the manual](https://cdn-global-hk.hobbyking.com/media/file/a/e/aerostar_rvs_esc_manual.pdf) says to enter the menu for the motor you must first set the throttle to 100%, then plug in the battery. A menu of beeps will be sounded and setting the throttle to 0 will then select and arm.

If I run the following command

```
pigs s 27 2500
```

plug in the power then... after the first set of 4 beeps run

```
pigs s 27 0
```

all goes quiet. I was expecting a confirmation beep.

If I then try and run any other pigs command to move the motor I either get nothing. Sometimes I get continuous beeps. It feels like it is not armed.

If I unplug the battry and plug it back in I get nothing (I am guessing I should get a sound to say it is armed?). I can re-enter the menu at any time with the above.

Anythoughts on what I need to do to arm the motor?

Comment: The normal maximum would be 2000.  Try that instead of 2500.

Comment: I had previously tried 2000, just tired again seems to have same effect unfortunately

Comment: Okay.  Instead of dropping to zero drop to the normal minimum of 1000.

Comment: Thanks will give that a go later

Comment: @joan that worked!!! If you add it as an answer I will mark as correct. Thank you for your help.

Comment: this question should be closed because it is unclear ... it lacks a connection diagram

Comment: Simpler if you self answer with how you managed to got it to work and tick it correct.

Answer (score 1):

When arming the ESC it is looking for the upper and lower values to set the range. For some reason setting the lower range to 0 (where it sends no signal) was not acceptable. Therefore the following works...

`pigs s 27 2000` (upper limit)

Wait for 4 beeps

`pigs s 27 1000` (lower limit)

Then hear the confirmation beeps. Following this we can send it further commands to spin the motor.